# How to send roles of a user in jwt token in identity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have done the token generation, but I want to send the user roles in the token as well.I also wrote some code related to sending the role, but it doesn't work properly.

I also have a problem with this prototyping.
var jwtAuthorizationManager = new JWTAuthorizationManager();

**This is my code**

public class JWTAuthorizationManager
{
private readonly UserManager _userManager;

```
    public JWTAuthorizationManager(UserManager<User> _userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = _userManager;
    }
    public async Task<JwtFeildsDto> Authenticate(string UserName, string PasswordHash)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
            //پیدا کردن همه نقش های کاربر


        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        //ایجاد تاریخ انقضای توکن
        var tokenExpireTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddHours(Constansts.JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRE_TIME);
        //ایجاد متغیر از کلاس مشخص شده برای ایجاد توکن و اطلاعات همراه آن
        var jwtSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        //ایجاد آرایه ای از بایت ها به عنوان کلید توکن
        var tokenKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Constansts.JWT_SECURITY_KEY_FOR_TOKEN);
        //از این کلاس برای نگهداری ویژگیها و اطلاعات درون توکن استفاده می شود.
        var List = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("username", UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimaryGroupSid,"User Group 01")

            };
        var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {

            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(List),

            Expires = tokenExpireTimeStamp,

            //امضا یا اعتبارنامه یا مجوز ورود
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(tokenKey),SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        foreach (var item in roles)
        {
            List.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));  

        }

        var securityToken = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
        var token = jwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
 

            return new JwtFeildsDto
            {
                token = token,
                user_name = UserName,
                expire_time = (int)tokenExpireTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds

            };

    }
   
}
```

---

```
    [HttpPost]

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] String userName, String 
password,bool remmberMe)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _loginService.UserLogin(userName, password,remmberMe);

            if (result == true)
            {
                var jwtAuthorizationManager = new JWTAuthorizationManager();
                var loginResult = jwtAuthorizationManager.Authenticate(userName, password);
                return Ok(loginResult);
            }
            else
            {

                return Unauthorized(MessageLib.Message.unaAuthorized);
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();

    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean about ` but it doesn't work properly.` ? I see you use `List.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item));` to add roles into claims, This is the correct way. The only error i find in your code you need to use `private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;` instead of `private readonly UserManager _userManager;`

Comment: My problem is that after instantiating this class  var jwtAuthorizationManager = new JWTAuthorizationManager(); It gives this error :

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter '_userManager' of 'JWTAuthorizationManager.JWTAuthorizationManager(UserManager<User>)'

Comment: Hi @sadegh, Please check the answer i updated.

Comment: I did this before, but I get the error 500. I put the picture of the error in the question, please check

Comment: Because your `Authenticate` is a async method, So you need to use await to call it, Please refer to my answer i updated.

Comment: The error was corrected, but the token is created without user roles, while the user has two roles in the database, and they are found, but they are not sent in the token. See the image of the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Constructor of `JWTAuthorizationManager`, it has a parameter `UserManager<User> _userManager`, So when you instantiate this class, you also need to pass the parameter type of `UserManager<User>` into it.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
     public HomeController(UserManager<User> _userManager)
     {
         this._userManager = _userManager;
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromForm] String userName, String password,bool remmberMe)
    {

            //.......
            var jwtAuthorizationManager = new JWTAuthorizationManager(_userManager );
            
            var loginResult = await jwtAuthorizationManager.Authenticate(userName, password);
    }
}
```